# How to put a condition in TWIG "if the user is flagged"?

Tags: 8, theming, users, flags

I have a site with Drupal 8 and the Flag module.

I would like to display a text when the user has the `association` role and when it is flagged with the following flag (his machine name):

```
flag_request_association_role
```

Then put its 2 conditions in a single line and how to know if the user is flagged ?

```
  {% if 'association' not in user.getroles and ??? %}
     <p>my text</p>
  {% endif %}
```

**UPDATE**

Here are my templates :

```
  {% if 'association' in user.getroles %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-success"></i> Votre compte association est actif.</div>
  {% elseif 'association' not in user.getroles and is_flagged_role_association %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-warning"></i> Votre compte association est en attente.</div>
  {% elseif 'association' not in user.getroles and not is_flagged_role_association %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-danger"></i> Votre compte association est inactif.</div>
    {{ content.flag_role_association }}
  {% endif %}

  <span class="border-top mt-4 mb-4"></span>

  <p>Les boutiques éphémères vous permettent d'exposer les créations des artisans présents sur la plateforme (pas de vente en ligne).</p>
  {% if 'pop_up_store' in user.getroles %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-success"></i> Votre compte boutique éphémère est actif.</div>
  {% elseif 'pop_up_store' not in user.getroles and is_flagged_role_pop_up_store %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-warning"></i> Votre compte boutique éphémère est en attente.</div>
  {% elseif 'pop_up_store' not in user.getroles and not is_flagged_role_pop_up_store %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-danger"></i> Votre compte boutique éphémère est inactif.</div>
    {{ content.flag_role_pop_up_store }}
  {% endif %}

  <span class="border-top mt-4 mb-4"></span>

  <p>Si vous êtes artisans, nous serions ravis de vous accueillir sur notre marketplace. Nous facturons une commission de 10% sur chaque vente. Vous recevrez une facture à chaque début de mois, si vous réalisez des ventes le mois précédent. Plus d'infos sur <a href="/node/271">cette page</a>.</p>
  <p>Pas de vente = Rien à payer</p>
  {% if 'marchand' in user.getroles %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-success"></i> Votre compte artisan est actif.</div>
  {% elseif 'marchand' not in user.getroles and is_flagged_role_artisan %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-warning"></i> Votre compte artisan est en attente.</div>
  {% elseif 'marchand' not in user.getroles and not is_flagged_role_artisan %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-danger"></i> Votre compte artisan est inactif.</div>
    {{ content.flag_role_artisan }}
  {% endif %}
```

bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old.theme :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for user.html.twig.
 */
function bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  $flag_id = 'flag_role_association';
  $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
  $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
  $user_to_flag = $variables['user'];
  $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $user_to_flag);
  $variables['is_flagged_role_association'] = $flag_status;

  $flag_id = 'flag_role_pop_up_store';
  $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
  $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
  $user_to_flag = $variables['user'];
  $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $user_to_flag);
  $variables['is_flagged_role_pop_up_store'] = $flag_status;

  $flag_id = 'flag_role_artisan';
  $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
  $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
  $user_to_flag = $variables['user'];
  $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $user_to_flag);
  $variables['is_flagged_role_artisan'] = $flag_status;
}
```

Comment: You can't declare the same function name more than once. You declare `function 
 bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old_theme_preprocess_user (&$variables) {` 3 times. You need to put each flag code all under **1** function.

Comment: 1 function, https://pastebin.com/2Vv6QTRt

Comment: it's cached, if you clear the cache should show proper text.

Comment: Shows  expected text for me after clearing cache, so I don't know.

Comment: @No Sssweat Ok thank you I found the problem. But the code created an error on most of my site https://pastebin.com/ku0ACkHH

Comment: You actually broke it and created a new error rather than "fix" it. It's just not possible for me to continue to help you at this rate with this particular question, sorry.

Comment: @No Sssweat  To correct I simply replace `function bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old_theme_preprocess_user(&$variables) {` by `function bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old_preprocess_user(&$variables) {` For the new error the code seems to work but there is a problem with this line `$flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $user_to_flag);` I deleted my template file to see if it corrects but it does not correct. So the problem is in the .theme file

Comment: @No Sssweat I had done the following module with you. Can this module create problems with my question? https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/zenimagine-3170711/-/blob/main/admin_task_notify.module

Answer (score 0):

**mytheme.theme**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for user.html.twig.
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  $flag_id = 'flag_request_association_role';
  $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
  $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
  $user_to_flag = $variables['user'];
  $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $user_to_flag); // get flag status
  $variables['is_flagged'] = $flag_status; // create variable for user.html.twig
}
```

> I would like to display a text when the user **has the association role**
> and when it is flagged

**user.html.twig**

```
  {% if user.hasRole('association') and is_flagged %}
    <p>my text</p>
  {% endif %}
```